# TypeError: e is undefined when chaining .done to ajax wrapper-function

Tags: jquery

I have created a small ajax function wrapper to start an `$.ajax` request.
It works, but when trying to add a function inside `.done`, `.fail` or `.always`, I'm getting this error: `TypeError: e is undefined`.

This is my javascrip/jquery ajax code:

```
var $ajaxScript = 'scripts/ajax.php';  //  controller-script that handles all ajax request
/**
 *  ajax wrapper()
 *  $_POST array with form posts
 */
function submitAjax($_POST){
    ajaxObj = $.ajax({url:$ajaxScript, data:$_POST, type:'POST', dataType:'json' });
    return ajaxObj;
}
```

Because all ajax form submission is sent through `ajax.php`, and that the returned data response for these requests is always set to json, I thought this would be a handy approach.
This allowed me to create a fast way to do a "default" ajax request by just adding the class `ajax` to the form.

```
$(function(){
    $("form.ajax").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        submitAjax($(this).serialize())
        .done(function(data,statusText,jqXHR){
            $(this).prepend('<div class="notice"><p class="icon">'+data['msg']+'</p></div>');  //  *--  this triggers a "TypeError"
            console.log('done : '+statusText);  //  <--  this alone doesn't throw any error
        })
        .fail(function(){
            console.log('fail');
        })
        .always(function(){
            console.log('always');
        });
    });
});
```

If I would need to handle the ajax request in a another manner, I could do so by creating a new function for it:

```
$(function(){
$("#updRecipe").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    /* do stuff before */
    var $Ajax = submitAjax($(this).serialize());
    /* do some more stuff */
    Ajax.done(function(){

    });
    /*  ...  do stuff at the end  ...  */
});
});
```

Here's the form layout I use:
By adding the class `ajax`, the form is treated as an ajax request using the code at the top.
The hidden field ´load-ajax´ is used by `ajax.php` to determen what script to use by the request.
The name of the `submit`-button is the identifier for what part, or section in the script is to be executed.

```
<form class="ajax">
    <input type="hidden" name="load-ajax" value="Recipe">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="<?=$get_recipe['name']?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit__updName" value="Oppdater oppskrift">
</form>
```

The code works when I have nothing, or just `console.log()` inside the methods. But it fails when I try to add other jquery functions.

`TypeError: e is undefined`, and the code is not executet correctly. Or, the output back to the user is not being executed corretly.

What am I doing wrong here?
The error only occurs when adding a function iside one of the methods...

Comment: How are you submitting the form? You need to either pass the event to the call or you have to condition the `.preventDefault()` on presence of the event (i.e.: `if (e) e.preventDefault()`)

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Not sure if I understood what you meant. I'm submitting the form with the click of the html `<input type="submit">`-button. The form has the class `.ajax` assign to it..  
It all works, but in order to give some feedback to the user, I'm trying to add a notice div container at the top of the submitted form using `.append()`...

Comment: You answered my question. I wanted to know if you're submitting programatically or using the form's natural native mechanism. I'll provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` inside `.done` callback of an `$.ajax` call refers to the jqXHR, which is an [Ajax event](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/) - basically a wrapper around the XHR call itself.

So, it's no longer the `<form>` (or, in some cases - not yours - , the `<button` that initiated the custom submit function).

Therefore, if you want to reference the `<form>` in the callbacks, you have to place a reference to it inside a variable of choice:

```js
$("form.ajax").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  let $form = $(this);

  /* do stuff before
   * `this` is <form> 
   */

   var $Ajax = submitAjax($(this).serialize());
   Ajax.done(function(){

     /* in here `this` is third param of the function, 
      * the jqXHR event 
      */

      $form.prepend('...');
    });

  /*  ...  do stuff at the end  
   *  `this` is still <form>  
   */
});
```

Comment: It's not from using jQuery *per se*. It's from using `this` which, inside the `success` callback, it's the [ajax event](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/).